# How to get 15 random images from a folder in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get 15 random images from a folder and show them on a page:
I tried the following code, however it did not do what I wanted:

```
$string =array();
$filePath='wp-content/themes/tema/img-test/';  
$dir = opendir($filePath);
while ($file = readdir($dir)) { 
   if (eregi("\.png",$file) || eregi("\.jpg",$file) || eregi("\.gif",$file) ) { 
   $string[] = $file;
   }
}
while (sizeof($string) != 0){
  $img = array_pop($string);
  echo "<img src='$filePath$img'  width='100px'/>";
}
```

Comment: array_rand() will help you here

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: word press isn't php, as word press is a subset.

Answer (score 1):

So, you have all the files in `$string` array, that's good.

You can either use the [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) function to get some random integer in the arrays size:

```
$string = ['img1.jpg','img2.jpg','img3.jpg'];
$rand = rand(0,count($string)-1);
echo $string[$rand];
```

You would have to loop that.

Or, you could use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) which will automate all that:

```
$string = ['img1.jpg','img2.jpg','img3.jpg'];
$amount = 3;
$rand_arr = array_rand($string, $amount);
for($i=0;$i<$amount;$i++) {
    echo $string[$rand_arr[$i]] ."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using the `glob()` function native to PHP. It will get all files in a directory. Following that you can pick one file from the retrieved list.

```
$randomFiles = array();
$files = glob($dir . '/*.*');
$file = array_rand($files);
for ($i = 0; $i <= 15; $i++) {
    $randomFiles[] = $files[$file];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. Your random image will be available in $arRandomFiles.

```
$filePath = 'wp-content/themes/tema/img-test/';  
$files = glob($filePath. '*.{jpeg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
$arKeys = array_rand($files, 15);
$arRandomFiles = array();
foreach ($arKeys as $key) {
    $arRandomFiles[] = $files[$key];
}
var_dump($arRandomFiles);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple function that handles that

```
<?php 
function getImg( $path ) {
    $filePath= $path . '*';
    $imgs = glob( $filePath );

    if( $imgs ) {
        $i = 1;
        foreach( $imgs as $img ) {
            if( $i <= 15 ) {
                $ext = pathinfo( $img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
                if( in_array( $ext, array( 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif' ) ) ) 
                    $r[] = $img;
            }
            else 
                break;
            $i++;
        }
        shuffle( $r );
        return $r;
    }
    else 
        return array();
}

print_r( getImg( 'wp-content/themes/tema/img-test/' ) );
```

Comment: Make sure the directory passed ends with a trailing slash (/) and returning that means no images found

Answer (score 0):

You can try function like:

```
function getRandomFile($directory)
{
    $directoryIterator = new DirectoryIterator($directory);
    $count = iterator_count($directoryIterator) - 2;
    foreach ($directoryIterator as $fileInfo) {
        $last = $fileInfo->getRealPath();
        if ($fileInfo->isFile() && (rand() % $count == 0)) {
           break;
        }
    }

    return $last;
}
```